# Is compactness a generalization of completeness

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Is the concept of compact spaces a generalization of completeness to non-metric topological spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite. A metric space space can be complete without being compact (e.g., $\mathbb R$ with the Euclidean topology). For a metric space, completeness + total boundedness = compactness.

Comment: You could argue that local compactness is the generalization, but that's not quite true either. The Baire space is not locally compact, but it is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Generalization of completeness to non-metric spaces goes through the concept of [uniform spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space).